# Centering a responsive website using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to have is centred content with left and right border on my website. The type of thing you get from having the code:

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However I'm using twitter bootstrap and still want to keep the website responsive, and doing the above seems to break the grid layout.

Can anyone advise me on the proper way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `span12`, as given in the [fluid grid documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem), as the root container would solve it out of the box, without breaking the in-built responsiveness.

Something like this - http://jsbin.com/amovub/5/edit

**EDIT:**
Uppdated the JSBin above to try and address the comment below. Essence is:

CSS:

```
.centeredContent{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="span12">
  <div class="centeredContent">

  <!-- your content -->

  </div> <!-- /centeredContent -->
</div> <!-- /span12 -->
```

Comment: I'm a bit lost at what you mean, how would using span12 as the container allow me to have 10% whitespace on the left and right side of the content?

Comment: @user2019957: Updated the JSBin and the answer with my thoughts... Hope that helps!

Comment: @user2019957: missed out to include the latest jsbin last time... now its updated

Comment: that does not work if you put in, say, 3 span4 columns, the 3rd column would go to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used twitter, but the standard method of centering an object in html using css with margins is as follows:

.container
    {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

Which ought to give the same results as:

.container
    {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
    }

and:

.container
    {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    }

Comment: I tried this (as shown in the css above), however as the responsive grid in bootstrap uses media queries to then set a fixed width for each column, the columns then overflow to the next line (so 12 columns do not fit anymore).

Answer (score 0):

THis page is one of the Bootstrap example pages which is also responsive:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

If you Firebug this page you'll see that the main 'container' class is simply using:

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: but how does it set the width?

Comment: @user2019957 - The width is built into the Twitter bootstrap responsive css file. The default largest width is 1170px which decreases via media queries when it has to.